# How to copy an excel sheet to a text container

Tags: excel, file-io, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

I do use selenium to automate the website I work. Here I have a rare scenario where a text container that represents data like a spreadsheet. So user is given with an option to copy data from spreadsheet and paste it the text container.

I would like to copy data from a sheet and paste same in the test container as a whole. So the test container displays the data in a table,  as it looks in excel.

Can anyone please help me with your suggestions......

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to automate a real Excel instance (you can't anyway), or the copy/pasting process. Just write the code to **directly set** a fixed amount of data (e.g. read from a file) into your container, and from then you can verify that it all appears / was saved etc.

How you get the test data into your test case, so that it can get inserted into the container, depends upon the way the container works.

If it's efficient enough, you can just use POI to load the contents of an Excel file (packaged in your project alongside your test), manipulate it into whatever format the container needs, and then set it.

If it's more efficient, just extract the test data once and store it in a text file for setting into the container, if that allows you to drop POI.